how to merge 2 lists of objects based on a particular field , and independent of values
I am having 2 lists of Dto objects, both are retireved from different BQ query. Example:
BQ result list 1 :
List<Data> bq1 = {
  [name:"abc", country: "ca", nbr:334],
  [name:"dcc", country: "ca", nbr:222], 
  [name:"aop", country: "in", nbr:234]
}

BQ rsult list 2:
List<Data> bq2 = {
  [color:a,  nbr:334],
  [color:n, nbr:334], 
  [color:e, nbr:234]
}

I want to combine both list based on nbr value and create new list.
expected:
List<Data> result = {
  [name:"aop", country: "in", nbr:234, color: e], 
  [name:"abc", country: "ca", nbr:334, color: a], 
  [name:"abc", country: "ca", nbr:334, color: n]
}

But when thee are more than one records with same nbr , i am getting only one set of values repeated.
Existing result:
List<Data> result = {
  [name:"aop", country: "in", nbr:234, color: e], 
  [name:"abc", country: "ca", nbr:334, color: a], 
  [name:"abc", country: "ca", nbr:334, color: a]
}

I am using Java8, Any help would be appreciated. Thanks
List<Data> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

Map<String, List<Data>> mapByItemNumber = bqList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getNbr));

for (Data item : bq3List) {

    if (mapByItemNumber.containsKey(item.getNbr())) {

        for (Data i : mapByItemNumber.get(item.getNbr())) {

            i.setColor(item.getColor());  
            resultList.add(i);
        }
    }
}


Please create a complete, minimal, runnable program which illustrates the problem.

I am able to get the list of objects , but for a particular id if there are 3 records with different field values , only one record is printed thrice, Any help for the same would be appreciated

Any solution would help

Here is the tested solution for your query, added a new constructor with all the values and mapped element data to it:
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Data> bq1 = List.of(new Data("abc", "ca", 334), new Data("dc", "ca", 222), new Data("aop", "in", 234));
        List<Data> bq2 = List.of(new Data("a", 334), new Data("n", 334), new Data("e", 234));

        Map<Integer, List<Data>> mapByItemNumber = bq2.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getNbr));

        List<Data> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Data data : bq1) {

            if (mapByItemNumber.containsKey(data.getNbr())) {
                
                List<Data> list = mapByItemNumber.get(data.getNbr());
                
                List<Data> collect = list.stream()
                        .map(item -> new Data(data.getName(), data.getCountry(), data.getNbr(), item.getColor()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                
                result.addAll(collect);
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(result);
        //output::
        //[Data [name=abc, country=ca, nbr=334, color=a],
        //Data [name=abc, country=ca, nbr=334, color=n], 
        //Data [name=aop, country=in, nbr=234, color=e]]

    }

}

class Data {

    private String name;
    private String country;
    private int nbr;
    private String color;

    public Data(String name, String country, int nbr) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.country = country;
        this.nbr = nbr;
    }

    public Data(String name, String country, int nbr, String color) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.country = country;
        this.nbr = nbr;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Data(String color, int nbr) {
        super();
        this.nbr = nbr;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public int getNbr() {
        return nbr;
    }

    public void setNbr(int nbr) {
        this.nbr = nbr;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data [name=" + name + ", country=" + country + ", nbr=" + nbr + ", color=" + color + "]";
    }

}


Hi. thanks for the response, but what if I have 50+ fields in Data dto. Do i have to get all 50+ fields in the line .map(item -> new Data(dat....

Instead of Constructor, you can use lombok with @Builder on class level and create object out of it and if you wants to perform any operation during object creation, simply create a method that return Data type and pass that method in map like: .map(item -> createDataObj(pass args here)). And if my answer solve your issue request you to upvote or accept as you like.
